# Migrating shape sql to something equally powerful

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

we are currently investigating a migration of an application that doesn't meet company standards. The application is built using VB6 and Shape SQL/Access. The application has about 120 reports by storing Shape SQL strings in a database which the user can modify using a wizard.
Shape sql is not allowed at this company. We have investigated plain SQL, Linq, Entity Framework as alternatives... but all result in more complex solutions.

Does anyone have another suggestion?

Update: Shape SQL is an ADO command to get hierarchical datasets, for further info: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said SHAPE is not allowed, but you could still use SHAPE against SQL Server through an ADO connection if you could get that criteria relaxed in the face of more difficult alternative implementations.

Have you looked at the XML features in SQL Server 2005 and up?

Hierarchical result sets are not typical relational database features, but you can do a lot with XML.

Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188919.aspx), too

Answer (score 0):

We have been in contact with Microsoft (in the Netherlands), their solution for now is to use Linq as a replacement. They also have contacted MSFT to get some responses, I will update my answer when we get more information.